# Efficient "macro" for adding second (x-)axis to pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, macros, axis

Lately, I have had to rely extensively on adding a second x-axis to my plots. I am doing so using the following script (see MWE), however, to me it seems quite inefficient and there's a lot of double work when I need to change parameters (width, height, position) of the main plot. Therefore, is there a way to write this as a "macro", i.e. something along the lines of the following:

```
\begin{axis} [
    name=plot_main,
    width=100mm,
    height=50mm,
    xlabel={$x$},
    xmin=0,
    xmax=10,
    ymin=-1,
    ymax=1,
    x2label={$T$},
    x2min=0,
    x2max=2.5,
    x2tick={0,1,2},
]   
    \addplot[color=red, domain=0:10, samples=100]{sin(360*(1/4)*x)};
\end{axis}
```

Thanks in advance!

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (node) {Example};
    \begin{axis} [
        name=plot_main,
        at={(node.north east)},
        anchor=north west,
        xshift=20mm,
        width=100mm,
        height=50mm,
        xlabel={$x$},
        xmin=0,
        xmax=10,
        ymin=-1,
        ymax=1
    ]   
        \addplot[color=red, domain=0:10, samples=100]{sin(360*(1/4)*x)};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis} [
        name=plot_second_axis,
        at={(node.north east)},
        anchor=north west,
        xshift=20mm,
        width=100mm,
        height=50mm,
        ymin=-1,
        ymax=1,  % The above all needs to be changed if the main plot changes
        xlabel={$T$},
        xmin=0,
        xmax=2.5,
        xtick={0,1,2},  % The below is all standard and never changes
        ytick=\empty,
        axis line style={draw=none},
        xtick style={draw=none},
        axis x line*=top,
    ] 
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: add_axis]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (node) {Example};
\pgfplotsset{
width=100mm, height=50mm,
ymin=-1, ymax=1,
}
\begin{axis}[
name=plot_main, 
at={(node.north east)}, xshift=2cm, anchor=north west,
xlabel={$x$},
xmin=0, xmax=10,
xtick pos=bottom,
]   
\addplot[red, domain=0:10, samples=100, smooth]{sin(360*(1/4)*x)};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
name=plot_second_axis,
at={(plot_main.south west)},
xlabel={$T$},
xmin=0, xmax=2.5,
xtick distance=1, minor x tick num=1, ytick=\empty,
axis line style={draw=none},
axis x line*=top,
] 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A sine wave graph with two x-axis]

Comment: If you have other graphs that do not need these settings, you need to put the settings and graphs inside `\begin{scope}` and `\end{scope}`

Comment: If you wish, you can wrap the second axis in a `\newcommand`, but if will only make life more complicated, as almost everything is custom for this specific axis.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer; however, in part for the reasons you mention (I have other graphs that don't need these settings), I don't really think this simplifies much. I would also get several nested scopes for certain plots which share other characteristics. It just introduced a lot of clutter, which becomes prone to error. As such, I hoped there would be a more simple way with `x2label={$T$}` etc. So avoiding `\pgfplotset` is a big pre