# Making keys global or reference them outside scope

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfkeys, key-value

I made this code to be used as an answer here: [Efficient "macro" for adding second (x-)axis to pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/710299/efficient-macro-for-adding-second-x-axis-to-pgfplots/710305#710305) and more generally.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{
mainaxis/.style={
tick pos=bottom,
before end axis/.code={
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}} \global\let\savedwidth\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/height}} \global\let\savedheight\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}} \global\let\savedxmin\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}} \global\let\savedxmax\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}} \global\let\savedymin\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}} \global\let\savedymax\pgfmathresult
}}}
\newenvironment{secondxaxis}[1][]{\begin{axis}[width=\savedwidth, height=\savedheight, axis line style={draw=none}, xtick pos=top, ytick=\empty, ymin=\savedymin, ymax=\savedymax, #1]}{\end{axis}}
\newenvironment{secondyaxis}[1][]{\begin{axis}[width=\savedwidth, height=\savedheight, axis line style={draw=none}, ytick pos=right, xtick=\empty, xmin=\savedxmin, xmax=\savedxmax, #1]}{\end{axis}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
name=main,
mainaxis,
width=10cm, height=5cm,
xmin=10, xmax=20,
ymin=30, ymax=40,
xlabel=main x, ylabel=main y,
%axis line style={draw=none}, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, %uncomment to see only second axis
]
\addplot[red, only marks] coordinates {(12,32)};
\end{axis}
\begin{secondxaxis}[
xmin=1, xmax=2,
xlabel=second x,
]
\addplot[green, only marks] coordinates {(1.5,34)};
\end{secondxaxis}
\begin{secondyaxis}[
ymin=3, ymax=4,
ylabel=second y,
]
\addplot[blue, only marks] coordinates {(18,3.6)};
\end{secondyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with axis on all four sides and three points]

How do I best reuse a key outside a scope? Does it need to be global, or can it be referenced some other way? e.g

```
\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/"name of scope"/"key in that scope"}
```

-or is it lost when the scope is closed?

If `width` and `height` is not given to the `axis`, they are not stored in keys. Can they be referenced anyway?

What is the best way to make a key global?

In the code, I use

```
\pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}} \global\let\savedwidth\pgfmathresult
```

but that seems somewhat backwards.

Comment: `pgfkeys` doesn't come with globally acting key handlers. You can search the site, there are a few answers adding them, but note that you're moving outside of the supported area of `pgfkeys` here.